# How to write correctly my own hotkey on lua for Awesome WM?

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I tried to add my own hotkey in my Awesome WM by editing rc.lua file.
Following the example of the structure of other hotkeys which are working correctly like:

```
awful.key({ altkey, "Control" }, "r", awesome.restart,
          {description = "reload awesome", group = "awesome"}),
```

I added this string:

```
awful.key({ modkey, "x" }, function () awful.spawn("kitty") end,
          {description = "open a terminal", group = "launcher"}),
```

This hotkey must open kitty terminal emulator after tapping "modkey(windows key)" and "x" keys. But after I restarted Awesome I received this message: `/usr/share/awesome/lib/awful/key.lua:122: bad argument #-l to 'key' (string expected, got function)`. I never wrote on lua and I don't understand why this error happened, because "x" is looking like string but not like function. Where I made the mistake? How to write it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

the correct entry for Mod + x is:

```
awful.key({ modkey, }, "x", function () awful.spawn("kitty") end,
          {description = "open a terminal", group = "launcher"}),
```

only modifying keys goes inside the curly braces